# Is it possible to create new keyevent to launch an android app?

Tags: android, adb

I want to create an button on navigation bar and launch an app when I tap on this button.
I found a way to create the custom button on navigation bar from below link
https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-add-custom-icons-to-the-navigation-bar-in-android-o/

`adb shell settings put secure sysui_nav_bar_left key(keycode_key:file:///storage/emulated/0/icon.png)`

This setting accepts a `keycode_key` of `keyevent` only. That why I am trying to find the way to create the custom `keyevent` with new `keycode_key` to launch an app when the `keyevent` is called (I know there is `adb shell am ...` command to launch an app but this button only accept `keyevent`).

Is it possible to create new `keyevent` to launch an android app? Or any programmable way to obtain this feature? Thanks.

Comment: If you can start an activity with `am` why would you need a keyevent that's trapped by system UI to be sent to the navigation bar to start an activity?

Comment: I want to start an activity by pressing on the custom button in navigation bar and the way to create the custom button `adb shell settings put secure sysui_nav_bar_left key(keycode_key:file:///storage/emulated/0/icon.png)` which triggers a keyevent instead of `am` command.